# Refreshing a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How will I refresh RecyclerView adapter when an item Is added. I tried using notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyItemRangeChanged(). But it doesn't seem to work. I am working on an app which allows two users communicate with each other through sending texts. The texts sent are retrieved in a RecyclerView. What I want to do is to refresh the RecyclerView of the other user when one of the users send a text. That is, refreshing the other users RecyclerView when a text is sent without having to refresh the entire activity.

Comment: I think you need to share your code here. By default notifyDataSetChanged() should do the work. Maybe you have forgot to add item to the list which is used to display elements in recyclerview

Comment: make sure the adapter reflects the data which should be shown before calling notify.

Comment: Am I supposed to add the notifyDataSetChanged() to the  adapter class or the adapter holder?